# Вложенные списки в python?

Tags: python, list

1. Как создать вложенный список `5x5`: и добавить в него значение `"MyValue"`, например, так?:

   `list[4][4]="MyValue"`
2. Как считать значение вложенного списка в переменную?

   `Str=list[4][4]`
3. Как итерировать по элементам вложенного списка в цикле(или во вложенном цикле)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

К сожалению, у вас многое неправильно.

Не называйте переменную именем встроенного типа.

Эта конструкция `list=[5],[5]` НЕ создает  список 5x5, а делает два списочка по одному элементу со значением 5, и объединяет их в кортеж (tuple)

Чтобы создать двумерный список, можно использовать списковое включение (я сделал покороче)

```
lst = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
```

или поэлементно добавляя  одномерные списки

```
 lst = []
 for i in range(3):
    lst.append([0]*3)
```

Если вы хотите добавлять элементы к подспискам, то это делается append-ом к элементам первого уровня

```
lst[2].append(6)
```

P.S. При сомнениях в правильности получаемых структур просто печатайте их print-ом

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: @MBoКак 
   -Как задать значение `'MyValue'` в листе `lst[2][2]` , должно получится в консоле вывода
`[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, MyValue], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`?И как вывести в консоле вывода значение `lst[2][2]?`  Можете помочь?

Comment: Задавать прямо так lst[2][2] = 'MyValue' - имеете в виду строку, да?  Вывести print(lst[2][2]) - какие сомнения?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Значит, у вас нет в списке такого индекса. Как вы его создавали?

Comment: я уже дал, первый же фрагмент нужно просто скопировать и изменить 3 на 5

Comment: -Извините, у меня все: получилось!!! А можно я опубликую свой ответ с готовыми функциями, это не будет плагиатом, просто там более точно развернут ответ, Можно так?

Comment: Да можно. Хотя что уж тут развертывать. Это же базовый синтаксис.

Answer (score 0):

Мой дивный друг, вот что получилось:

```
ls=[0]*10 #Создаем лист, 1D (одномерный) из 10 элементов
lst=[]    #Создаем лист, пока без размера (в будущем 2D list)
lst0=[]   #Создаем лист, пока без размера (в будущем 3D list)

ls.append("11") #добавляем в конец списка ls элемент со значением "11", даже если элемента нету
ls.insert(8,"888") #добавляем в середину списка ls в 7-ю строчку элемент со значением "888"
ls[7] = 667 #добавляем в 6 элемент значение (667) (если не определить размер массива то это не сработает)
print(ls)    #выводим принтуем 1D список 

def Create_2D_List(X,Y): #Создаем функцию создания листа с размерностью (X)*(Y)
    global lst
    lst = [[0]*X for _ in range(Y)]
    
def Create_3D_List(X,Y,Z):#Создаем функцию создания листа с размерностью (X)*(Y)*(Z)
    global lst0
    lst0 =[[[0]*X for i in range(Y)] for j in range(Z)]

def Fill_2D_List():#Заполняем 2D-лист: lst стандартными значениями
    global lst
    X = len(lst)
    Y = len(lst[0])
    for x in range(X):
        for y in range(Y):
            lst[x][y]=str (x)+' '+ str(y) #стандартное сзначение 
      
def Fill_3D_List(): #Заполняем 3D-лист: lst0 стандартными значениями
    global lst0
    X = len(lst0)
    Y = len(lst0[0])
    Z = len(lst0[0][0])
    for x in range(X):
        for y in range(Y):
            for z in range(Z):
                lst0[x][y][z]=str (x)+ str(y) + str(z)#стандартное сзначение 


Create_2D_List(4,7)   #Создали массив 2D 4*7
Create_3D_List(2,4,8) #Создали массив 3D 2*4*8
Fill_2D_List()        #Заполинили 2D массив
Fill_3D_List()        #Заполинили 3D массив

lst[0][0]='MyValue_2D'#Наполинили 2D массив
lst0[0][0]='MyValue_3D'#Наполинили 2D массив

print(lst)                   #Отобразили в консоле массив
print('=-----------------=') #Отобразили в консоле массив
print(lst0)                  #Отобразили в консоле массив
```

Comment: Зачем вам глобалы? Создавайте список в функции и возвращайте его return-ом

Comment: @MBo, а как итерировать грамотно? Есть функция длины списка, но, сын, - у нас вложенный список, как сделать по x.len() и по y.len()?

Comment: Я тоже против глобалок, тем более что [в функциях Python есть встроенный баг](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRg9v.png) на глобалки.

Comment: @DiMithras    **1.** Исправьте, мой ответ, сделав без глобалок, **2.** А как сделать 3-х мерный список 3x5x7?

Comment: Не не не, исправления не для этого. Можно написать просто параллельный ответ ссылаясь на вопрос и ответ, в рамках правил. Про многомерный массив не совсем понятен вопрос, это просто вложенные списки.

Comment: @DiMithras    Тогды напишите, ваш Вариант в ответе. Я и спрашиваю как сделать lst[][][]? Чтобы можно было: `lst[2][3][8]=MyValue`?

Comment: По аналогии же `lst = [[[0]*3 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]`

Comment: @DiMithras , Сработало, надо же!?!)) А как правильно узнать length для lst[2][3][8] Например как при вложенности максимум 2x3x8, узнать длину length x, y, z.  А именно как узнать x.getLength, y.Length() и len(z) и так далее не могу понять как это реализовать в питоне? должно получится
`x: 2, y: 3, z: 8`

Comment: @ArthurAlunts допусть в переменной x трёхмерный массив. `len(x)` покажет первый уровень, `len(x[y])` покажет второй уровень, где **y** индекс. Ну и так далее до `len(x[y][z]`. Если надо найти для всех элементов, то можно сделать это в цикле.

Comment: Ребят, вроде бы получилось. Опубликовал ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я понял чего вы хотите. `make_nlist` создаёт вложенный список по списку размеров. Например `make_nlist([2, 3])` создаст "двумерный" список размера *2×3*:

```
def make_nlist(dim):
    if len(dim) == 0:
        return None
    head, *tail = dim
    return [make_nlist(tail) for _ in range(head)]
```

`fill_nlist(nlist, cb)` заполняет вложенный список значениями. Значения вычисляются в функции `cb`, в которую передаётся кортеж из индексов:

```
def fill_nlist(nlist, cb):

    def traverse(index, nlist):
        for i, v in enumerate(nlist):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                traverse(index + (i, ), v)
            else:
                nlist[i] = cb(index + (i, ))

    traverse((), nlist)
```

Пример использования:

```
import pprint


pprint.pprint(make_nlist([2, 3]))

a = make_nlist([2, 3, 4])
pprint.pprint(a)

fill_nlist(a, lambda index: ''.join(map(str, index)))
pprint.pprint(a)
```

> ```
> $ python nlist.py
> [[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
> [[[None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]],
>  [[None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]]
> [[['000', '001', '002', '003'],
>   ['010', '011', '012', '013'],
>   ['020', '021', '022', '023']],
>  [['100', '101', '102', '103'],
>   ['110', '111', '112', '113'],
>   ['120', '121', '122', '123']]]
> ```

Comment: -> Спасибо за Ваш труд!